Python Using Oauth (2) to Connect to Google API on Google Cloud Shell. Stuck on flow.run_local_server(port=0)
This program works on my local machine but when I run on Google Shell it behaves differently.  After confirming my sign-on with Google and accepting the app is not verified etc, and which Google attributes my program can access.  It sends me to a long URL that http://localhost:37985/.....
I ran curl on my Google Shell and it continued until it crashes and I get this error
OAuth2 flow: (missing_code) Missing code parameter in response.
I cannot figure out what next to do.  I would really appreciate if someone can take pity on my and help me out.  I have been working on this for weeks.  TIA
Here is the program
# python glogon5.py  (my 5th attempt after trusting ChatGPT and Gemini)
# training program to authenicate to google and use the APIs for userinfo, calendar, tasks, email READONLY
# developed on local box and works well.  It pops a browser window open and lets me pick from the Google account on my machine

# deploy to Google Shell in the GCP
# 7-12-2024 Google Shell works like local up until:
# After comfirming my sign with Google and accepting the app is not verified etc, and which Google attributes my program can access
# It sends me to a long URL that http://localhost:37985/.....  
# I ran curl on my Google Shell and it continued until it crashes
# OAuth2 flow: (missing_code) Missing code parameter in response.
# I cannot figure out what next to do 

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

import google.auth
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow      import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery      import build

#mport google.auth.exceptions
import os
import sys
import pickle

#what os and how was executed
import platform
print(f"pwd           =", os.getcwd()                   )
print(f"os            =", os.name                       )
print(f"computername  =", os.environ.get('COMPUTERNAME'))
print(f"username      =", os.environ.get("USERNAME")    )
print(f"os_version    =", platform.platform()           )
environ_keys = ' '.join(os.environ.keys())
flask_running = 'WERKZEUG' in environ_keys
print(f"flask_running =", flask_running                 )

if len(sys.argv) > 1: email=sys.argv[1]
else: email="bracyr@gmail.com"

SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks.readonly',
    #this ones fails the program when refresh the pickle file if openid is not added
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email','openid'
    ]

def oauth2():
    flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    # Check if previously saved credentials exist (i convert later to storing creds as current best practices)
    pickled="token_"+email+".pickle"
    if os.path.exists(pickled):
        with open(pickled, 'rb') as token: 
            credentials = pickle.load(token)
    else:
        #my Google Shell problem is here 
        try:
            credentials = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error("ERROR: In my oauth2 function with the flow.run.. port=0: %s", e)
            raise
        # Save the credentials for future runs
        with open(pickled, 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(credentials, token)

    creds=credentials
    return creds    

def glogon():
    #expired creds will not be revealed until actually pulled on servitem line    
    creds=oauth2()
    service = build('oauth2', 'v2', credentials=creds)
    try: #must wait till the execption to find out if it is expired
        servitem= service.userinfo().get().execute()
    except google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError:
        print(f"The credentials are expired")
        os.remove("./token.pickle")
        servitem={'email': 'Email not availabe creds expired.'}  #dummy the servitem list
        creds=oauth2()  #try it again (all three statements tempted to put them in function)
        service = build('oauth2', 'v2', credentials=creds)
        servitem= service.userinfo().get().execute()
    except Exception as e:  #all other errors kill it
        print(f"Exception: {e}")
        print(f"Program will termniate")
        sys.exit(0)
    return creds, servitem

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # This block will only run if the script is executed directly.
    creds, servitem = glogon()
    print("creds=",creds.valid)  # updated on previous statement
    print(f"Email: {servitem.get('email')}")
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

    #pull calendar data to see if worked
    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    servitem= service.events().list(calendarId='primary',fields='items(summary,start,end)',maxResults=2).execute()
    print("creds=",creds.valid)  # updated on previous statement
    print("Cal chk -->",servitem['items'][0]['summary'])
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

    #pull task data to see if worked
    service = build('tasks',    'v1', credentials=creds)
    servitem= service.tasks().list(tasklist='@default',maxResults=2).execute()
    print("creds=",creds.valid)  # updated on previous statement
    print("Task chk-->",servitem['items'][0]['title'])
    print("------------------------------------------------------------------------------")

I created it locally and worked fine.  I cannot replicate it on Google Shell.

Is the error message missing_code or is it something about the redirect_uri ? The google cloud shell can sometimes fail to url-encode the redirect_uri. Please share the exact error message you are seeing
